# Angular.js dynamically load directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm quite new of Angular.js development. 
I am building a walking skeleton in which:

1. the controller of a page, defined in the routing part, retrieves a meta-configuration from the backend with the components to load into the page (e.g. 
   `{"component1":"directive1", "component2":"directive2"}`)
2. in the view, Angular.js renders the right directive

In a nutshell I would like to create a repository of different directives all related to the same view that could be selected by the backend.

The view:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="{{page.component1}}"> </div>
<div class="{{page.component2}}"> </div> 
</div>
```

The controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
.controller('PatientListPageCtrl', function ($scope, patientListPage) {
  $scope.page   = patientListPage.getData();
 });
```

The service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
.factory('patientListPage', function ($resource) {

return $resource('/data/navigation/patientsList.json',{ }, {
    getData: {method:'GET', isArray: false}
});
});
```

A directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
.directive('directive1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        templateUrl: '../../templates/directives/patientsList.html',
        controller: 'ListaPazientiCtrl',
        replace: true
    }
});
```

Doing so, the component is not being displayed in the page although the tag is present.

Now, I tried with `class` and `ng-class`, both. In the rendered HTML there's the right directive inside the class but it renders void. I presume Angular.js needs to re-traverse the DOM or just re-compute the page but how to do it?

Thank you for your help

Comment: what *exactly* is the problem? what is not happening as expected?

Comment: the component is not displayed in the page although there is the corresponding html tag

Comment: Probably the directive is fired before the template is compiled. Why don't you simply create a common directive and switch template based on an attribute?

Comment: Here is [a great tutorial](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/) on how to use different templates with the same directive.

Comment: Well it's not just about switching template in the directive.. could also be the controller, business logic, everything.. so really it should be possible to dynamically use different directives

Answer (score 0):

Directives cannot be "dynamically added" to the live DOM and expected to work, because your template is only compiled once. If you wish to construct a template dynamically, you can surely do that, but do it separately from your DOM and then [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) it, bind it to appropriate scope, and insert it into the DOM manually.

Inside your "dynamic inclusion" directive, you can do something like:

```
$http(/* ... (load some data) */).success(function (data) {
    var template = angular.element('<div>')
        .attr(data.directive.name, data.directive.value);
    $element.empty().append($compile(template)($scope));
});
```